# 'heapdump.xxx.phd'. Not a HPROF heap dump (java.io.IOException) Not a HPROF heap dump

Tags: eclipse-memory-analyzer

The Eclipse Memory Analyser docs say it can open IBM portable heap dump files (*.phd):

http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.mat.ui.help/welcome.html

However, when I try to open one I get and error:

```
'heapdump.xxx.phd'. Check the error log for further details.
Not a HPROF heap dump (java.io.IOException)
Not a HPROF heap dump
```

I've tried both menu options (File > Open Heap Dump) and (File > Open File)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to install DTJF in order to read IBM files.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/MemoryAnalyzer#System_Dumps_and_Heap_Dumps_from_IBM_Virtual_Machines

Eclipse download site is at the bottom here:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/tools/dtfj.html

Answer (score 0):

The eclipse MemoryAnalyzer throws the exception:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Parsing heap dump from 'D:\XXXX.phd'".
int is not an array
```

So I have to use IBM HeapAnalyzer:
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/websphere/appserv/support/tools/HeapAnalyzer