# Installing DTJF on Eclipse Memory Analyzer to read .phd files

Tags: heap-dump, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I have Eclipse Memory Analyzer v1.3.1, and need to analyze some .phd heap dumps.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868926/heapdump-xxx-phd-not-a-hprof-heap-dump-java-io-ioexception-not-a-hprof-heap), it is necessary to install DTJF on Eclipse Memory Analyzer.

[This link in the question](http://wiki.eclipse.org/MemoryAnalyzer#System_Dumps_and_Heap_Dumps_from_IBM_Virtual_Machines) says: Memory Analyzer can also read memory-related information from IBM system dumps and from Portable Heap Dump (PHD) files. For this purpose one just has to install the IBM DTFJ feature into Memory Analyzer version 0.8 or later. Follow the [IBM DTFJ feature installation instructions](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/tools/dtfj.html). If the DTFJ feature is successfully installed then 'File' 'Open Heap Dump' should give the following options for the file types ......

When I click on the link from the "Installation" section, I arrive at [this location](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/runtimes/tools/dtfj/) which seems to be a file listing with some .jar files and 1 .xml file, but no installation instructions.

Does anybody know what I am supposed to do? I have not installed Eclipse Memory Analyzer v1.3.1 "properly" - I just downloaded all the files and put them under C:\Users(my username)\Documents\Software\MemoryAnalyzer-1.3.1.20140107-win32.win32.x86\mat and normally run it by double-clicking the file MemoryAnalyzer.exe. Do I have to do something before DTFJ can be installed?

Comment: I found another alternative software (Heap Analyzer) which supports .phd files, still would be good to get it working on Memory Analyzer - Heap Analyzer is voracious on memory and really slows down the computer when running.

Answer (score 11):

The location  http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/runtimes/tools/dtfj/ is an Eclipse update site. You can use it to install the DTFJ plugin by going to Help->Install New Software in Memory Analyzer and adding it as a new update site location.

Alternatively you can use a build of Memory Analyzer with the IBM DTFJ feature already installed using IBM Support Assistant. There's more instructions for that on the IBM devloperworks site here:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/tools/memoryanalyzer/